# Subgroup of a group with one relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've started to learn combinatorial group theory. Could someone to make clear next question:

Let G be a group G=< a,b,c | [[a,b],c] = 1 > and let H be a subgroup in G:

$H=<aba^{-1} b^{-1}, b^2,c^2 | ...>$.

Is there an additional relation in H: $[aba^{-1}b^{-1},c^2]=1$?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose that $H=\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1}, b^2, c^2\rangle$ is meant. Then $H$ is just the smallest subgroup of $G$ with the condition that it contains $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $b^2$ and $c^2$. Nevertheless, we know that in $G$, $[a,b]$ commutes with $c$, hence also with $c^2$. If I'm not mistaken, this observationmakes $H$ isomorphic to the following group prsentaion: $\langle u,v,w\mid [u,w]=1\rangle$.

Comment: Why need to restrict to $H$? The same is already valid in $G$. (In $G$, $[a,b]$ commutes with $c$, therefore it commutes with $c^2$.) Did you mean to ask something else, e.g. whether $H$ is isomorphic to a free group generated by some $a'$, $b'$ and $c'$ (that mean to be $[a,b]$, $b^2$ and $c^2$) with relation $[a',c']=1$?

Comment: I fixed some typesetting problems. Take a look to be sure that I did not change the intention of your question.

Comment: @Hagen it is not immediate than there are no other relators (finitely generated non-free subgroups of one-relator groups are not necessarily one-relator groups, even once you have discarded the "obvious" examples of, e.g., free products of finite cyclic groups). I think you can use Britton's Lemma for HNN extensions to show that the new identity can be taken be to *the* defining relation for the subgroup (the stable letter is $c$), but I have not verified the calculation on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By given $$(aba^{-1}b^{-1})c=c(aba^{-1}b^{-1}),$$ which gives 
$$(aba^{-1}b^{-1})c(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}=c$$ or
$$(aba^{-1}b^{-1})c^2(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}=c^2,$$
which gives, which you want.